# SAS Arrays within Macro

Tags: arrays, loops, macros, sas

[image: Scatterplot]

I try to use a scatterplot template I created within a loop so that I can catch every plot combinations but I see that I cannot use call symputX for arrays. How can I find a turnaround for such cases?

Above you can find one of the scatterplot example for only one combination.

Thank you

```
  data work.mycsv;
  set work.mycsv;
  array temp[3] x y z;
  call symputX('temp',temp);
  run;
  %macro scatter();
  %let i = 1;
  %do %while (&i <= 3);
  %let j = %sysevalf(&i+1);
  %do %while(&j <= 3);
    %if &i ne &j %then %do;
      proc template;
        define statgraph scatterplot;
            begingraph; 
                entrytitle "Title"; 
                    layout overlay;      
                         scatterplot x=&&temp[&i.] y=&&temp[&j.] / 
                         group=Survived name="scatter" datalabel=Response;
                         discretelegend "scatter";
                    endlayout;  
            endgraph;
      end;
  %end;
%let j =%sysevalf(&j + 1);
%end;
%let i = %sysevalf(&i + 1);
%end;
%mend scatter;
%scatter();
proc sgrender data=work.mycsv template=scatterplot;
run;
```

Comment: There is no concept of a macro array. An analogy would be a list and you access each item in turn, see the example here http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/mcrolref/69726/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p1n2i0ewaj1zian1ria5579z1zjh.htm

Comment: What do you want the macro variable TEMP to contain? How many observations are in the source table MYCSV?  Post a simple example of MYCSV and the resulting SCATTERPLOT statements that you want to generate?

Comment: Hello Tom, I added the scatterplot example for only 1 combination, I want to generate the same for all combinations,(In this case 3 combinations). I have 3 numerical parameters and 900 observations.Regards

Comment: @Reza, Thank you so much. I solved it by using the link you provided

Comment: I don't understand what combinations are you talking about? Are you talking about 2-way combination of the three variable X, Y and Z?  x=X y=Y, x=X y=Z, x=Y y=Z?

Comment: It would help if you had a stand-alone example, say using the SASHELP library or datalines

Comment: @Tom, The combiations are x vs y, y vs z and x vs z. In this case there are only 3 but if the column number increases then combinations will eventually increase as well, Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually if you want to store a list of values in macro variables you should just use a delimited string. If the list is of variable names then it is easiest to use space as the delimiter.

```
%let varlist= X Y Z ;
```

Then you could easily construct macro logic to find all two way combinations.

```
%let nitems=%sysfunc(countw(&varlist));
%do i=1 %to %eval(&nitems-1);
  %let var1=%scan(&varlist,&i);
  %do j=%eval(&i+1) %to &nitems ;
     %let var2=%scan(&varlist,&j);
     ....
  %end;
%end;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 %macro scatter();
 %let varlist = x y z;
 %let i = 1;
 %do %while (&i <= 3);
 %let j = %sysevalf(&i+1);
%do %while(&j <= 3);
 %if &i ne &j %then %do;
    %let x_used=%qscan(%bquote(&varlist),&i);
    %let y_used=%qscan(%bquote(&varlist),&j);
    proc template;
        define statgraph scatterplot;
            begingraph; 
                entrytitle "&x_used and &y_used by Response"; 
                    layout overlay;      
                         scatterplot x=&x_used y=&y_used / 
                         group=Survived name="scatter" datalabel=Response;
                         discretelegend "scatter";
                    endlayout;  
            endgraph;
            end;
            proc sgrender data=work.mycsv template=scatterplot;
  run;
  %end;
%let j =%sysevalf(&j + 1);
%end;
%let i = %sysevalf(&i + 1);
%end;
%mend scatter;
%scatter();
```